Puppet Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server ... Unknown variable: 'operatingsystem'
I am new to puppet and I am trying to understand the following.
In all manifests i see using top scope variables used like $::operatingsystem, $::operatingsystemrelease, $::hostname etc. but when i run puppet agent it complains about unknown variables.
If I query them with facter operatingsystem in shell then it works.
I use puppet server/agent version 8.x.x and I found in some
documentations that this is the wrong way to use these top scope variables and should be used instead as $facts['os']
From what i see, facter returns:
"os": {
"distro": {
  "release": {
    "full": "24.04",
    "major": "24.04"
  },
  "codename": "noble",
  "description": "Ubuntu 24.04 LTS",
  "id": "Ubuntu"
},
"release": {
  "full": "24.04",
  "major": "24.04"
},
"architecture": "amd64",
"family": "Debian",
"name": "Ubuntu",
"hardware": "x86_64",
"selinux": {
  "enabled": false
}
}...

so $facts['os']['name'] should be the equivalent of $::operatingsystem, and then it works.
My questions are:

is  there a config somewhere that enables those hashes/variables?
is then better to use $facts['variable']... ?


Puppet 8.x.x does not recognize top scope variables like $::operatingsystem.
Instead, use the facts hash instead. This method is modern and "future-proof".
The old way:
if $::operatingsystem == 'Ubuntu' {
  notice("This is Ubuntu ${::operatingsystemrelease}")
}

The new way:
if $facts['os']['name'] == 'Ubuntu' {
  notice("This is Ubuntu ${facts['os']['release']['full']}")
}

Good luck!

Thanks. Now i have to figure out what other things changed. For example I use an ENC and even if i have modules that "require" other modules/classes, seems like puppet is not able to figure out where is that module/class unless i include the modules mentioned in the ENC node cfgs as well.
